# How do you deploy a golang google cloud function with a custom go build constraint/tag?

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am using go build constraints to conditionally compile constants into my test/staging/production cloud functions. How can I pass `-tags ENV` to the builder used by `gcloud beta functions deploy`?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. But you can use Cloud Run instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Guilherme mentioned in the comments, indeed, it seems that it's not possible to pass the `go` constraints/tags to the builder used by Cloud Functions.

I searched around and while there isn't this option, I think indeed, having the option to send constraints to the builder used by Cloud Functions. Considering that, I would recommend you to raise a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this to be checked by Google.

One option that you might want to give a look at it, it's deploying your application using Cloud Run. As it's informed in their [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run) about this application:

> Use the programming language of your choice, any language or operating system libraries, or even bring your own binaries.
>
> Cloud Run pairs great with the container ecosystem: Cloud Build, Container Registry, Docker.

So, this might work for you as a workaround. In this below tutorial, there are the steps to build and deploy a quick application with Go in Cloud Run.

- [Quickstart: Build and Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#go)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks. It did. I think my solution will be environmental variables for now. Not really ideal and risks a misalignment between the cloud functions and application, but the former are just so easy to hack. But I suspect I'll discover Run is a better choice soon enough.